# Error with PHP Mcrypt extension for PHP 7.1 and Amazon Linux 2

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I am working on a project that is working on PHP 7.1 and MySQL 5.7(this application requires PHP mcrypt). Now the customer wants to host it on Amazon Linux 2. But whenever I try to set this up server, I cannot find the php-mcrypt package anywhere for Amazon linux 2.

I know that mcrypt is deprecated, but please advise if anybody knows how to set this up on Amazon linux 2.

**Disclaimer**: Not an expert on setting up servers.

Comment: PHP 7.1 went [EOL back in December 2019](https://www.php.net/eol.php) and MySQL 5.7 goes EOL in October this year. Perhaps it's time to upgrade? Have you tried using [PECL](https://pecl.php.net/package/mcrypt) to install? This question would probably be better suited to [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/).

Comment: Did you try `sudo yum install -y php-mcrypt`?

Comment: @ArpitJain Yes I did, but it says no package available

Comment: @user1191247 it’s stable application even the tech stack is outdated, for company money is important. However migration is in progress

Comment: @RintoGeorge, can you try the steps I have written in the answer? I ran these steps on my amazon linux ec2 instance and was able to install php-mcrypt.

Comment: @ArpitJain Sure I will try it and let you know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the below steps to install the `php-mcrypt`:-

1. To ensure that all of your software packages are up to date, perform a quick software update on your instance.

   `sudo yum update -y`
2. Install the `php7.1` Amazon Linux Extras repositories to get the latest versions of the PHP packages for Amazon Linux 2.

   `sudo amazon-linux-extras install -y php7.1`
3. Now that your instance is current, you can install the `php-mcrypt` or any other PHP software package.

   `sudo yum install -y php-mcrypt`

   This will install `php-pecl-mcrypt` and the dependency package `libmcrypt`.
4. You can view the current versions of these packages using the following command:

   `yum info php-pecl-mcrypt`

Hope this helps.

Comment: It works on Amazon Linux 2, Thanks!

Comment: @RintoGeorge, Glad to know it helped you :)